# why does $X,Y\in L_2,\langle X,Y\rangle=E(XY)$

Tags: probability-theory, analysis, normed-spaces, hilbert-spaces

why does $X,Y\in L_2,\langle X,Y\rangle=E(XY)$

I've seen this a lot recently, and I know that $E(\cdot)$ properties satisfied the definition of inner product, what really bugs me is as follow:

$$\langle X,Y\rangle=\sum x_iy_i\neq\sum\sum x_iy_if(x,y)=E(XY)$$

Please help.

Comment: I suspect that the places where you've seen that equation use $L_2$ to mean the space of square-integrable (or square-summable in the discrete case) functions on a probability space (or more generally on a measure space). In that case the formula for the $L_2$ norm and the inner product would include factors involving the probability (or more general measure). In your situation (finite sums) those factors would be the probabilities $p_i$ of the points $i$ in your probability space $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thank you for your reply. what you suspect is correct, but I do not clear with your saying that includes probability stuff. Would you please tell me more about that?

Comment: Look carefully at the definition of $L_2$ of a measure space and its inner product. Specialize it to the case of a probability space where the underlying set is $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ and the measure of each singleton $\{i\}$ is $p_i$.

Comment: I guess what you are missing is "with respect to what probability measure" are these things defined. Indeed, if the probability measure considered is $\pi$, then the inner product wrt $\pi$ does match the expected value wrt $\pi$, which is why you often write $L_2(\pi)$ to make it precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the setting of probability theory, $X,Y \in L^2$, means $\mathbb{E}[|X|^2] < \infty$ and similarly for $Y$. Furthermore,
$\langle X,Y \rangle$ is defined (notationally) to mean $E[XY]$ for random variables $X$ and $Y$.

Now for the sum you have above:
$\sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i $, this is the Euclidean inner product which uses the same angle bracket notation for vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Context is crucial to pay attention to as there is only so many ways to denote things without making math indecipherable. Moreover, both are instances of inner products so it makes sense to use the same notation.

Example of context being important : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wick_product